# Bash scripting: Deleting the oldest directory

Tags: bash, file-io, directory, delete-directory

I want to look for the oldest directory (inside a directory), and delete it. I am using the following:

```
rm -R $(ls -1t | tail -1)
```

`ls -1t | tail -1` does indeed gives me the oldest directory, the the problem is that it is not deleting the directory, and that it also list files.

How could I please fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not pretty but it works:

```
rm -R $(ls -lt | grep '^d' | tail -1  | tr " " "\n" | tail -1)
```

Comment: Be careful: it does not work if the directory name contains spaces.

Answer (score 8):

```
rm -R "$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%T@\t%p\n' | sort -r | tail -n 1 | sed 's/[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\t//')"
```

This works also with directory whose name contains spaces, tabs or starts with a "-".

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -R $(ls -tl | grep '^d' | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f8)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find directory_name -type d -printf "%TY%Tm%Td%TH%TM%TS %p\n" | sort -nr | tail -1 | cut -d" " -f2 | xargs -n1 echo rm -Rf
```

You should remove the echo before the rm if it produces the right results