# removing all but X oldest directories on FreeBSD via Bash (no -printf, with spaces, no zsh)

Tags: bash, freebsd

There are several different topics on stackoverflow regarding find/removing the oldest directory/files in a directory .  I have read a lot of them and seen a myriad different ways that obviously work for some people on other systems but not for me in my particular case.

The constraints are:

- Im on FreeBSD (Freenas 9.3)
- Directories have spaces in them
- Dont use ls (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- Cannot use -printf of find (doesnt exist for me)

The closest i have gotten is something like this (not complete):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -d -name "Backup Set*" -print0 | xargs -0 stat -f "%m %N" | sort -r| awk 'NR>5'
```

This gives me the directories that I want to delete however they now have timestamps prepended, which I am not sure that if i strip out and pipe to rm i will be back to a situation where i cannot delete directories with spaces in them.

output:

```
1450241540 ./Backup Set1
1450241538 ./Backup Set0
```

Thanks for any help here.

---

relevant posts that I have looked at:

https://superuser.com/questions/552600/how-can-i-find-the-oldest-file-in-a-directory-tree

[Bash scripting: Deleting the oldest directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612257/bash-scripting-deleting-the-oldest-directory)

[Delete all but the most recent X files in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785/delete-all-but-the-most-recent-x-files-in-bash)

Comment: does the `stat` output let you put in extra dbl-quotes, i.e.`stat -f "%m \"%N\%""` ? Good Q, Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
... | awk 'NR>5' | while read -r timestamp filename; do rm -rf "${filename}"; done
```

When there are more fields than variables specified in `read`, the remainder is simply lumped together in the last specified variable.  In our case, we extract the timestamp and use everything else as-is for the file name.  We iterate the output and run an `rm` for each entry.

I would recommend doing a test run with `echo` instead of `rm` so you can verify the results first.

---

Alternately, if you'd prefer an `xargs -0` version:

```
... | awk 'NR>5' | while read -r timestamp filename; do printf "%s\0" "${filename}"; done | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

This also uses the `while read` but prints each filename with a null byte delimiter which can be ingested by `xargs -0`.

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried the former and it works - with the caveat that you have to run it from a script , I was not able to run it directly from the command line as i had been testing my commands this way.

Answer (score 0):

piping this cut command `cut -d ' ' -f 2-` will take out the timestamp

simple example

```
echo '1450241538 ./Backup Set0'|cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

will get rid of the timestamps

results will be

```
./Backup Set0
```